# Javascript make objects appear when searched for

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm making a website that has a map of a campus on it and the idea is that the user clicks on a particular building, bringing them to a new page which then prompts them to enter the room's code.  That I've got under control, but what I don't know how to do is to have a little marker appear on the location of the room on the map (bearing in mind that each building has multiple rooms). The entire webpage needs to dynamically alter its size (ie the map itself is a variable-sized image), so I can't simply put markers on top of the image.  How can I make it so they enter the room code (eg they enter '101') and a marker (say an image) will appear at the location of that room (see images below).

[image]

### Edit

I am currently using the source below.  As you can see, I use a prompt box to get the room code, and what I want is to get a particular image and position it at a specified position.

```
    <script language="Javascript">
        var roomCode = prompt("Please enter the room code", "Enter room code here");
        if(roomCode==='101')
        {
            /*Put image in particular location*/
        }
        else if(roomCode==='102')
        {
            /*Put image in particular locationr*/
        }
        else
        {
            alert("That room does not exist.  Please refresh the page and try again.");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: have you checked out jquery /jquery ui yet? it has some helpful positioning functions.

Comment: @attila no I haven't and I'm a nube at JS, so I've no idea what that is!  I'll look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, add an ID to each room that corresponds to the room code for each room and name your room code form to store the user input:

```
<img id="MarkerForRoom101" style="display:none">

<form id="EnterRoomCodeForm"><input type="text" name="roomcode"><button type="button" 
onclick="ShowRoomCodeImage()">Click</button></form>
```

For each room, also have the number of pixels from the left and number of pixels from top stored in a form (call it room coordinates form or whatever, coordinates stored as 2 separate values).

Then, when a user enters a room code number in the form (by clicking your form's button), you use javascript to change the display of the user inputted room:

```
function ShowRoomCodeImage() {
    var roomcode = document.forms.EnterRoomCodeForm.roomcode.value.trim();
    var leftcoordinate = document.forms[RoomCoordinateForm][roomcode + 'left'].value;
    var topcoordinate = document.forms[RoomCoordinateForm][roomcode + 'top'].value;
    document.getElementById('MarkerForRoom' + roomcode).style.marginLeft = 
    leftcoordinate + 'px';
    document.getElementById('MarkerForRoom' + roomcode).style.marginTop = 
    topcoordinate + 'px';
    document.getElementById('MarkerForRoom' + roomcode).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when the picture resizes?  Won't it show the marker in the wrong place?

Comment: Can you describe how your scaling/resizing function is constructed/defined?

Comment: Here's the scaling snippet: <Style type="text/css">
            img {width:100%; height: auto; }
            img {max-width: 500px}

Comment: OK...the user scales the image by clicking an icon on your site?

Comment: No, all the images automatically scale based on the window size.  I know it works because I've tested it.

Comment: You will have to get the height and width of the window relative to the user's full screen (you will need screen.availWidth, $window.width(), $(window).height() and screen.availHeight), then scale your 'leftcoordinate' and 'topcoordinate' by this amount. So if the code I wrote is for 100% scale, and (assuming a square campus map) the window is 81% (by area, which means 10% reduction of x and 10% reduction of y), then newleftcoordinate = 0.9*leftcoordinate and newtopcoordinate = 0.9*topcoordinate. If a rectangular campus map, you will need to know the relative dimensions of length and width.

Comment: For width scaling factor, try var windowWidth = $window.width(); var scaledWidth = (windowWidth / screen.availWidth)

Comment: I have posted my current source based on your answer, but I'm at a loss as to how to incorporate the location values (I'm working on how to actually get the markers to appear at the moment, and I'll worry about the variable locations later on)